# C# List of generic class/type as a property or memeber of a class

Tags: c#

I am not sure how to create a `List` that holds elements of a generic data type using C#.

Currently I have two very similar classes defined in my code:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

    public List<SpecialClass> data { get; set; }
}

public class ClassTwo
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

    public List<YTDTRNSLine> data { get; set; }
}
```

My current thought process was that I should generalize these two classes into one class. Since the only difference is one of the properties which is a `List`.

Do I define the `List` with something like this:

```
public List<object> data {get;set;}
```

?

When I tried to use `List<object>`, I tried to do something like this:

```
ClassOne classOneObj = new ClassOne();
classOneObj.data = myFunctionHere();
```

Where `myFunctionHere()` returns a `List` of a datatype/class which I have defined on my own. When I do this, there will this error message shown:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type List<MyOtherClass> to List<object>.
```

I am stuck as of now. How do I go about create a list of a generic type? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Make your class generic using `public class MyClass<T>` then in your property definition `public List<T> data { get; set; }`

Comment: Do `ClassOne` and `ClassTwo` represent the same business entity? What does `SpecialClass` and `YTDTRNSLine` have in common?

Comment: As an aside (unrelated to the question, but just a general suggestion), now would be a good time to learn about and start following the [.NET naming conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the classes are so similar, I would join them entirely. There is a problem though with the different types on the `data` classes, but you can solve that with generics:

```
public class ClassOne<T>
{
    public int draw { get; set; }
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }

    public List<T> data { get; set; }
}
```

Then define the variables as:

```
ClassOne<SpecialClass> classOneObj = new ClassOne<SpecialClass>();
ClassOne<YTDTRNSLine> classTwoObj = new ClassOne<YTDTRNSLine>();
```